# Printing error messages from console instead of closing shiny app

Tags: function, error-handling, shiny, montecarlo, flexdashboard

I have a shiny app that runs a monte carlo simulation with 500 replications.  To do this, I use a for loop and call a function from another package to run the simulation, and then I save the data.  The shiny app then produces the results using renderTable.

It is possible that the user could mistakenly enter something that would cause one or more of the replications to fail to converge, triggering a `stop` in the function I'm calling.  If this happens, there is nothing to render in a table.  In R, I get a nice error message from the package telling me that the model failed to converge.  However, in Shiny, the app just force closes.

I'm currently using `tryCatch` and `showNotification` to display this notification in the app (see below):

```
observeEvent(input$go,
tryCatch({
  simulation_results()
},
  error = function(err){
    showNotification(paste0(err), type = 'err')
})
)
```

It works well, but the problem is that it causes the app to take 6x longer to run (it goes from ~1.5 min to ~10 min).  I think this is because it's trying to catch and show the notification from every individual replication in the for loop.  The app also still does close; it just displays the error first (which I do appreciate).

**Is there a [faster] way to get shiny to print error messages from the console instead of closing the app?**

I was thinking of validate, but I don't know how it would work - what I really need is something like
`validate(need("no error message in the console"))`.  I tried using `validate(need(simulation_results(),geterrmessage())` to see if it would simply print the last error message if there were no simulation results, but the app shuts down once it gets to the `stop` error in the function.

Also, I'm using `flexdashboard` if that changes anything.

Comment: Generally speaking, `try-catch` shouldn't affect the performance of your R code that much, please post as much sample code as possible to reproduce

Comment: It turns out that the app was closing because it was trying to observe an event that was failing.  This was also causing it to not display the error message.  Removing the eventReactive from the observeEvent solved it!